# Cambiar base de datos con hibernate en ejecución

Tags: hibernate

Buenos dias

Consideren este escenario tengo una tabla de `usuarios` atributos `(nombreUsuario,nombreBaseDatos)`

Cuando un usuario se conecta el sistema identifica quien es el usuario y envía la información a hibernate para conectarse a la base de datos correspondiente.

ahora adjunto la parte del codigo del hibernateUtil

```
    public static synchronized void buildSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null ) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Responsable.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Proceso.class);


        configuration.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        configuration.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        configuration.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "usuario" );
        configuration.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "contrasena" );
        configuration.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+base);
        configuration.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        configuration.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", base);
        configuration.configure();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    }
}
```

En donde dice base, envio cual es la base de datos que quiero conectar, el sistema funciona con el primer usuario, el problema sucede con los siguientes, la información que carga es del primer usuario y no del actual.

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan aportar, espero haber sido claro en mi duda.

Comment: Cuando se ejecuta la primera vez `sessionFactory ` es nulo, entonces se procesa el codigo que nos muestras. Pero la siguiente vez, por la condición ya no se ejecuta el codigo y se queda con la primera configuración

Answer (score 0):

La clave del problema puede estar en la inicialización de la variable "base". Utiliza la consola para saber con que valores arranca la variable con cada usuario.

Espero te sirva mi respuesta, saludos.